# Google Sheets Array Formula: repeat formula for new responses

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula in one of the columns:

```
=(MAX(C2:F2)-MIN(C2:F2))/AVERAGE(C2:F2)
```

Currently, I am manually updating this formula column every time a new response has been added from Google Forms. I tried using the `ARRAYFORMULA`, but I cannot get it to populate the new rows.

1. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to repeat the formula for new entries?
2. Is it possible to email the recipient back with the newly calculated column value after they have submitted the Google Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"ARRAY FX"; ARRAYFORMULA((QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C2:F), 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , IF(LEN(C2:C),
 "max(Col"&ROW(C2:C)-ROW(C2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")), "select Col2")-
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C2:F), 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , IF(LEN(C2:C),
 "min(Col"&ROW(C2:C)-ROW(C2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")), "select Col2"))/
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C2:F), 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , IF(LEN(C2:C),
 "avg(Col"&ROW(C2:C)-ROW(C2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")), "select Col2"))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The formula works perfectly!